# What's the best practice to get data from onActivityResult to fragments?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

My parent activity is launching another activity and needs its fragments to update when the results are returned via onActivityResult.  Should I simply implement methods in each fragment to pass the data into them, or is there a different way this should be done?

Thanks!

Comment: I would use event bus (http://square.github.io/otto/) for this, but simple method to pass a result would do the trick as well

Comment: You cannot access an existing fragment directly from an Activity. However a fragment can get its own Activity since that is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Make your fragment that should receive data implement an interface with a suiting method.

In the activity when the result is returned from onActivityResult, use the `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("yourtag")` method to find the fragment. Cast it to the interface and call the method is has.

Make sure to check if the fragment actually exists after calling `findFragmentByTag`.

Comment: This worked for me, but my fragment's onResume promptly stomped my value with the old one from the Bundle originally passed into the fragment.  Is it safe to always ignore the Bundle's data if a value already exists, or are there other scenarios where a fragment may be reused and the Bundle  should override?

Comment: @Dennis perhaps you should only look in the Bundle when the fragment is first created and not when it is resuming.

Answer (score 0):

If  the fragment is the one making the startActivityForResult call, the activity gets the first shot at handling the result. This makes sense when you consider the modularity of fragments. Once you implement super.onActivityResult for all unhandled results, the fragment got a shot at handling the result.

To get the result in your fragment make sure you call : startActivityForResult(intent,123); instead of getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,123); inside your fragment.

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: using startActivityForResult in fragment solved my problem. So easy.

Answer (score 0):

Someday I will have to solve your issue or similar. Per my understanding, you'll have to implement an interface between Activity and a Fragment. The link is at [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) . The webpage seems clear unlike other Google pages. A snippet of code:

```
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

Almost always, class **FragmentTransaction** is involved in managing data. Note how **Bundle** is used to pass data, also to get data from the client side.
Have fun, keep us posted.